# Collect all used loggers in java application

Tags: java, logging

Im configuring a support site in which we want to be able to change all the log levels of the used loggers in the app. It is requested that even the loggers from the used libraries can be configured. Is it possible to get a collection of all the loggers of an app?

I am not sure how to import and use different Logger/LogManager in one class. For example we are using java.util.logging.LogManager, org.slf4j.Logger, org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager, ...

Are there examples or best practices how to do this?